# Can't get properties of GstBaseSink on GstXvImageSink in pygst

Tags: python, pygtk, gstreamer, python-gstreamer

I'm trying to access the "last-sample" property from GstXvImageSink which is derived from GstBaseSink.
I'm getting:

> TypeError: object of type 'GstXvImageSink' does not have property 'last-sample'

Is there a special way to get properties from base classes in pygtk or is this property somehow hidden?

Code:

```
def take_snapshoot(self):
    sample = self.__snapshot_source_video_sink.get_property("last-sample")
```

Comment: Did you try `get_last_sample()`?

Comment: @elya5 Yes, with this code:    sample = self.__snapshot_source_video_sink.get_last_sample()' I'm getting:
AttributeError: '__main__.GstXvImageSink' object has no attribute 'get_last_sample'

Answer (score 0):

My fault. I'm using gstreamer 0.1 and I was reading documentation for gstreamer 1.0
Everything that was reffering to GstBuffer is now GstSample.
After http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/manual/html/chapter-porting-1.0.html

> GST_TAG_IMAGE, GST_TAG_PREVIEW_IMAGE, GST_TAG_ATTACHMENT: many tags that used to be of type GstBuffer are now of type GstSample (which is basically a struct containing a buffer alongside caps and some other info).

So in my case the answer is to use:

```
def take_snapshoot(self):
sample = self.__snapshot_source_video_sink.get_property("last-buffer")
```